# I want to use the gallery swipe in home page

Tags: javascript, jquery

The thing is that,How can i use the photoswipe javascript on page load rather than when trigred with  tag. Is there a way or I have to search for alternatives?

Comment: give us more details and show us some code. we are not wizards to identify your problems from nothing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly just change

autoStartSlideshow: True

because the default is set to false as stated in the documentation of photoswipe.

autoStartSlideshow: Automatically starts the slideshow mode when PhotoSwipe is activated. Default = false